# Search for place where variable is given value

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, static-analysis

Is there any mechanism within VS Code (including plugins) to search for the place where a variable is given a value? I often search for `myvariable =` but that doesn't catch things like:

```js
{ myvariable } = ...
[ myvariable ] = ...

function myfunc(myvariable) { }
myfunc(myvalue)
```

I'm working with JavaScript exclusively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is the right stack exchange for this question, but yes, there is a way to find these. The article on [code navigation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved) will help you further. Basically, VS Code has a command "Find references" (for me it's keybind `F12` or `ctrl+shift+F12` for a "full" version, but I don't know if this is the default) which will show you where a variable/type is declared **and used**.

As far as I know, there isn't an easy way to find **only** the places where a variable gets **assigned**. But these are included in the references search.

Comment: (Yes, questions about IDEs and other tools used by developers are on-topic.) That feature looks great - it looks easy enough to skim the results to find. It even seems to pick up references in JSDoc comments, which is pretty interesting.

Comment: Programming tool questions are specifically mentioned as on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to open the `Go to symbol in editor` menu.

Here you can search for variable definitions, and once selected your cursor will automatically be moved to the definition.

### Example

**Say my file looks like this:**

[image]

**I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to bring up this:**

[image]

**Then I can select an item to move my cursor to the definition like this:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this feature! It doesn't seem to include function parameters, for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another idea just for fun.  It uses an extension I wrote, [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#overview), that handles your request pretty easily (as long as you can make the appropriate regex ;>}).

With this keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "alt+y",                  // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "find": "${selectedText}(?=\\s*[}\\]]?\\s*=)",
    "isRegex": true,
  }
}
```

It'll get your selected text (which may just be the word under the cursor - see demo) and uses a positive lookahead to find the examples you mentioned in your question.  The match will be scroll-revealed if necessary.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to return the cursor to your previous position.

[image: selected text with reveal demo]

Comment: Ah, so essentially it allows you to map search-and-replace strings to key bindings?

Comment: Yes, that was a big part of the original inspiration.  I also wanted to use launch/task-like path variables in find/replace as well as some snippet concepts like conditional replacements that can't be done in a find.  It has expanded to a few other useful variables like lineNumbers, matchNumbers and the resultsFiles to easily run a second search across files using only the files found in a prior search.